# L1953T-BF Monitor won't turn on, not even the led light, all of a sudden

Tags: display

I have a 4 year old LG L1953T-BF monitor. It has been working perfectly since I bought it and I never made extreme uses of it.

I've been working on my PC yesterday and played video games and, all of a sudden, this morning, the monitor won't turn on.

I can't even see the led light on it. Any clues how I could fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Check the fuse in the plug (if you are in a country that has fuses in the plugs).

If it has an external power brick then use a voltmeter to test the output voltage of that.

If the fuse has gone, replace it.

If there is no power coming out of the power brick then maybe buy a replacement from the manufacturer.

Comment: Tried with different power cables, the problem really comes from the Monitor and not from the plug.

Comment: There will probably be an internal fuse in the monitor itself that may have blown.